# LyX possible bug in Outline > Table of Contents > search?

Tags: lyx, search

In [this LyX file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E0KZcxlncLyp1edNJ4cRFUNs7D8dzEBv/view?usp=share_link), when I search for "add" (at Outline pane > Table of Contents > "Filter:"), "1 \ln", "2 \exp", and "3 \sin" appear:

[image]

Is this a possible bug? Or am I just doing something wrong and need to change some settings?

I'm using LyX Version 2.3.6.1 (Tuesday, December 29, 2020). I think this didn't happen in 2.2.x and before.

---

It seems that searching for any string also "works":

[image]

---

It seems that the problem is with any forward or backward slashes:

[image]

Comment: It seems that the problem occurs only when a title contains a backslash (also in LyX2.3.6)

Comment: @UdiFogiel: I think it also happens with forward slash (see added screenshot)

Comment: could you open a bug ticket in here https://www.lyx.org/trac/newticket ? you might need to contact the developers to get access, you can send an e-mail to the address  lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org

Comment: @UdiFogiel: could you do it instead (if you already have access)?

Comment: I will, in a few days.

Comment: I think this has been fixed with LyX 2.3.7?

Comment: looks like it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has now been fixed in LyX 2.3.7 (January 7, 2023).

Comment: I think you should probably accept this answer (the check mark on the left side), this way the question will be considered as solved.